# Submit autofill (password input field)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I want to submit an autofilled password form using a userscript/tampermonkey in chrome. However it doesn't work - <s>the fields</s>  **the password field** remains empty (server response or even with alert messages) until the window is actually controlled by a user (any actual keyboard press or mouse click). *This seems important if you want a userscript to automate logins without hard-coding the passwords into your userscript.*

Does anyone have an explanation for that and/or a workaround?

I tried all ways I know to submit the form: .submit() or dispatching an actual mouseclick event, etc

Try it yourself: Autosave password/name here: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_PASSWORD.html

additional info: Tampermonkey version 3.12.58, chrome Version 49.0.2623.110 m, Windows 10 64x. I also tried deactivating all extensions in chrome.

Userscript that goes with that page:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_PASSWORD.html
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

//wait 5s to assert that chrome autofill had enough time to do its thing
setTimeout(function(){document.forms[0].submit()},5000)
```

edit: looping code that never submits.

```
loopme()

function loopme() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        //check every second if 'password field' is empty, if not, submit the form
        if(document.forms[0].elements[1].value != ''){
            document.forms[0].submit()
        } else {
           //make count visible
           document.title = "|" + document.title
           //edit: adding an virtual 'click' makes no difference:
           //var mouseClick = new MouseEvent("click");
           //document.body.dispatchEvent(mouseClick);
           loopme()
           }
    },1000)
}
```

screenshot of password field because of [this suggestion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=378419) based on a chrome bug. 
Left: form before submission, right: server response.

[image][image]

(verbose) logfiles of chrome when running the looping-script:

```
Navigated to http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_PASSWORD.html
content: Started (5edc5230-099a-412a-bca4-48c97edb3113, http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_PASSWORD.html)
content: start event processing for 5edc5230-099a-412a-bca4-48c97edb3113 (1 to run)
env: initialized (content, id:5edc5230-099a-412a-bca4-48c97edb3113, http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_PASSWORD.html) 
env: schedule 'New Userscript' for document-idle
env: schedule for later events!
env: first DOMNodeInserted Event!
content: Started (d2f1e833-ce3f-48e8-a81c-cf4a93475a98, nullblank)
content: disable event processing for d2f1e833-ce3f-48e8-a81c-cf4a93475a98
content: Started (6b10cff5-a3a1-4eab-9286-f7e49aaa5952, http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_PASSWORD.html)
content: disable event processing for 6b10cff5-a3a1-4eab-9286-f7e49aaa5952
content: Started (dc4a5836-69a6-4194-a631-ad2354cc6a33, nullblank)
content: disable event processing for dc4a5836-69a6-4194-a631-ad2354cc6a33
env: DOMContentLoaded Event!
content: detected DOMContentLoaded 5edc5230-099a-412a-bca4-48c97edb3113
content: Started (df53f06c-55ba-4398-8a4d-0b41d2fb3f93, nullblank)
content: disable event processing for df53f06c-55ba-4398-8a4d-0b41d2fb3f93
env: execute script New Userscript @ the safe context now!
content: Started (069446ea-3b29-42c4-8c13-9f4f112f6a01, https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/html/r20160331/r20151006/zrt_lookup.html)
content: disable event processing for 069446ea-3b29-42c4-8c13-9f4f112f6a01
content: Started (127600e6-61f8-4e15-862a-fe0aaa6e4683, http://s7.addthis.com/static/sh.953eb77977227bfd253ee158.html)
content: disable event processing for 127600e6-61f8-4e15-862a-fe0aaa6e4683
content: Started (b50036dc-266a-4328-92b9-6937c09419e3, https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads)
content: disable event processing for b50036dc-266a-4328-92b9-6937c09419e3
content: Started (5df2993f-2fc5-4f40-8fa9-aa37c7ffd987, https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads)
content: disable event processing for 5df2993f-2fc5-4f40-8fa9-aa37c7ffd987
content: Started (8f6c166e-6e61-4776-ba28-8caf786704f4, http://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-2/html/container.html)
content: disable event processing for 8f6c166e-6e61-4776-ba28-8caf786704f4
content: Started (c9082438-936d-4ba3-b76e-bf7cc9f48bae, https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads)
content: disable event processing for c9082438-936d-4ba3-b76e-bf7cc9f48bae
content: Started (2439efaa-3ea5-461b-a8a1-25b2be866f1a, https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads)
content: disable event processing for 2439efaa-3ea5-461b-a8a1-25b2be866f1a
content: Started (fdd7347c-3bf8-4e05-a9bb-97e0e26d543e, https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads)
content: disable event processing for fdd7347c-3bf8-4e05-a9bb-97e0e26d543e
content: Started (5e2a844c-fe1e-4c8d-af07-09b3b1ab272c, https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads)
content: disable event processing for 5e2a844c-fe1e-4c8d-af07-09b3b1ab272c
content: Started (0cef6828-3752-4b05-a8de-68cb90f6b29b, https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads)
content: disable event processing for 0cef6828-3752-4b05-a8de-68cb90f6b29b
content: detected load 5edc5230-099a-412a-bca4-48c97edb3113
content: Started (65ce238d-9bd8-45cd-8d52-8d215ae3fe62, https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads)
content: disable event processing for 65ce238d-9bd8-45cd-8d52-8d215ae3fe62
content: Started (c3747272-9bf6-4a6b-baf3-d38b7fbb8134, nullblank)
content: disable event processing for c3747272-9bf6-4a6b-baf3-d38b7fbb8134
```

Comment: Please add more info about your question, such as your sample code.

Comment: added, please keep in mind that I don't actually want to read/intercept the password values. On the contrary I DON'T want to read them, but submit them. However as far as my testing goes, servers do NOT receive the chrome autofilled name/password if a userscript automatically submits the form (even after setTimeout etc) - UNLESS you provide some sort of 'real' user action (eg clicking, pressing a key). I suspect it's a safety measure on chrome-side, but... I don't know and I really would like my script to work =)

Comment: sorry but still unclear about your question... You want to simulate a submit action but the code you provided did nothing?

Comment: Let me specify: I want to auto-submit a form by userscript, that is auto-filled by chrome with username/password. However the submitted forms only include empty fields unless there is actual user-interaction with the page. The script shows merely that you cannot read it by alert messages until there is user-interaction (since I cannot provide the server-side answer) Edit: Sorry, the page even lists the server-side answer - I changed to code

Comment: I have the same problem in tampermonkey on a page. There is a show/hide icon in the password field. When I click with the mouse on it or inside the input field, the tampermonkey script continues, but when simulating the click inside the script  the password value remains empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there appears no one can answer: Here's the best answer I found on a similar topic (without an explanation). Please share if you find or have better information...

The **password-field won't be populated** (by autofill) **without an explicit instruction from the user** and can therefore not be accessed by javascript.

From [Stackoverflow question: Can JavaScript access autofilled passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416926/can-javascript-access-autofilled-passwords)

Comment: So where does that leave people who want to submit autofilled passwords from a userscript? Is it simply impossible?

Comment: as far as I know, yes